# How to pass multiple json variable to view in ajax from codeigniter controller.?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I want to pass two variable of  json to ajax from controller here I have little code of it.

```
echo json_encode($qry1);
echo json_encode($qry2);
```

How can I get this both in ajax and How can I use it like `data.qry1` and `data.qry2`.

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>getdata",
        type: "POST",           
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{Paper_name : p_name},

        success : function(data){                   


            if(data != ""){                 
              alert(data.qry1);

            }else{                                  

             alert(data.qry2);
       },
       error : function(data){

        alert(data.qry2);
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge both independent array to one single array

```
$dataArray = array(
    'qry1' => $qry1,
    'qry2' => $qry1
);

echo json_encode($dataArray);
```

In ajax, add `console.log(data)` and check how its comming

Comment: is it possible to get length of this. like data.qry1.length.?

Comment: Yes can. individual array can be get length

Comment: @Mahi happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Put the two variables into an associative array:

```
$qry = array(
    'qry1' => $qry1,
    'qry2' => $qry2
);

echo json_encode($qry);
```

Comment: is it possible to get length of this. like `data.qry1.length`.?

Comment: It should be, yes... assuming that's javascript :-)

Comment: Aww man, I was faster by 20 sec, lol.  Abdulla, you get an upvote from me :-)